# TikZ matrix in TikZPoster

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzposter

Using a TikZ matrix in a TikZPoster does not work.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\block{Some title}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [matrix of nodes] {
            A & B \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

It gives the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options
```

Any suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `ampersand replacement=\&` as argument for `tikzpicture` and replace all `&` with `\&`

MWE

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\block{Some title}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
        \matrix [matrix of nodes] {
            A \& B \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]